# Buttons looks disabled until I click something

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button bound to a `ICommand`

```
<Button Content="Remove" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}" x:Name="btnRemove" Visibility="Collapsed" />
```

After some tasks is done, I made the button visible, except that they *look* disabled until I click something, why is that? The `RemoveCommand` looks like below

```
public ICommand RemoveCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_removeCommand == null)
        {
            _removeCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                if (RemoveRequested != null)
                    RemoveRequested(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }, () =>
            {
                // CanExecute Callback
                if (Status == WorkStatus.Processing || Status == WorkStatus.Pending)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Returning False" + Status); return false;
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("Returning True"); return true; // After uploads, this returns True, in my Output Window. 
            });
        }
        return _removeCommand;
    }
```

after uploads, the `CanExecute` callback returns True, so button should be enabled, but it looks disabled till I click something, why is this happening?

[Video of the Problem](http://screenr.com/qqF)

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`.**

This method should call the `CanExecute()` on the commands and that should update the `IsEnabled` of your buttons.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx for more information.

Comment: This question was asked quite a while ago, but I'm having the same problem as @jiewmeng. I explicitly call InvalidateRequerySuggested(), but it still isn't updated until I do a focus change. jiewmeng, did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

If `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` does not do the job, try forcing the focus on the control containing the buttons at the appropiate time (MouseEnter, Loaded...):

```
//void ParentControl_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
void ParentControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Focusable = true;
    this.Focus();
}
```

It might not be the most elegant solution but worked for me.